# How to retrieve data from multiple tables by joining on keys ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I m developing staff records management system for a company using ROR3
I m new to ROR. Just started one month ago. So facing some troubles when developing the application.

these are some tables

### 1- profiles

```
id
service_number
first_name
last_name
```

### 2- promotions

```
id
service-number
rank
date_of_rank
```

### 3- unit_allocation

```
id
service_number
unit
date_from
date_to
```

Actually the service number is the unique ID number for the employee. So I wanna join tables using service number

This a raw sql I used to generate some info. but I couldnt do it in ROR

```
SELECT promotions.service_number, profiles.first_name, promotions.rank, 
promotions.date_of_rank
FROM profiles, promotions
WHERE promotions.service_number = profiles.service_number
AND promotions.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM promotions WHERE service_number = 3975)
```

In the profiles index page I want to show profile detail plus current rank and unit of the employee

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [JOINS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) rather than [Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) then you would be looking at this:

```
Profiles.joins("JOIN promotions ON promotions.service_number = profiles.service_number")
```

and then expanding that to emulate your query:

```
@promotions_id = Promotions.select("max(id)").where(:service_number => 3975)

Profiles.select("promotions.service_number, profiles.first_name, promotions.rank, promotions.date_of_rank").joins("JOIN promotions ON promotions.service_number = profiles.service_number").where("promotions.id = ?", @promotions_id)
```